# Update the sort order in a database using PHP from the jQuery sortable plugin

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using a jQuery plugin to sort the product order. It's working fine on the client site but I also want to update the order in the database. Here is my attempt: HTML:

```
<ul id="item_list" >
<li id="item_1">Item One</li>
<li id="item_2">Item Two</li>
<li id="item_3">Item Three</li>
<li id="item_4">Item Four</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#item_list").sortable({stop:function(i) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "server_items_reorder.php",
    data: $("#item_list").sortable("serialize")
  });
  foreach($_GET['item'] as $key=>$value) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE my_items" SET position = '" . $key . "' WHERE id ='" .         $value . "'");
```

But I do this, it throws an error: show invalid arguement for foreach. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your code might be based on [Wil Linssen's post](http://linssen.me/entry/extending-the-jquery-sortable-with-ajax-mysql/).

Whether it is or not, “invalid argument for foreach” means that `$_GET['item']` is empty, or not in the correct format.  Try printing it in `server_items_reorder.php`:

```
print "$_GET[item]";
```

Answer (score 0):

mm.. I think that the name of querystring var is item_list

try this for rename

```
$('#item_list').sortable('serialize',{key:'item'})
```

Are you sure that #item_list contains the ids value??

Comment: yes...#item_list contains the ids value and i am trying to update the database but its not doing ...here is my html code <li id=item_1>data1</li>

Comment: Ok, check alert($("#item_list").sortable("serialize")) before the ajax call and if show something as "item[]=..&item[]=.." etc , the problem is on server_items_reorder.php.
print the value of $_GET in  server_items_reorder.php

foreach($_GET as $k => $v)
 echo "$k -> $v<br/>";

and check that $_GET['item'] exists, may not arrive to server_items_reorder.php